# changing int to Integer iterator basic java

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I'm writing an inner class that implements iterator and I'm trying to return an integer for one of my methods but it won't let me. I know this is a very fundamental question but I'm new to java so I'm sorry for how simple it sounds.

```
public class pIterator<Integer> implements Iterator<Integer>{

private int currentEx = 1; 
private int base = 4; 

//error says can't convert int to Integer here specifically 
private Integer changeToInteger = base * currentEx++;  

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
  return currentEx <= max;  
}

//the problem then occurs here when I try to return an Integer 
@Override
public Integer next() throws NoSuchElementException {
 if (currentEx > max) throw new NoSuchElementException(); 

 return changeToInteger; 
 } 
}
```

currentEx and base must be ints (as defined by instructions) so should I just change the return type or can I cast to an integer?

Comment: currentEx was pre defined in my constructor as an int though so I have to keep it that way.. .

Answer (score 6):

You're hiding the standard `java.lang.Integer` by defining your class as a generic class with a parameter named Integer. It should be defined as

```
public class pIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
```

Otherwise, your class is the equivalent of

```
public class pIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
```

but with `T` confusingly named as `Integer`.

Comment: do you know what effect currentEx++ has on incrementing the variable? everytime next() is called will currentEx increase by one?

Comment: No. Why would it, since this is done in the constructor of your class, and not in the next() method? And why don't you test it?